# How to update a column in SQL using values propagated from a "select" statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have column that I have queried using select statement. I want to add this column onto my table. The statement is:

`select vd.*, a.rate from vacation_days vd left join Algorithm a on v
d.work_days between a.day1 and a.day2 group by id`

This returns a column with three rows each with decimal rate. 
This is what I tried to do:

```
update vacation_days set vacation_days.free=vd.days_CurrYear*(select vd.*, a.rate from vacation_days vd left join Algorithm a  on v d.work_days between a.day1 and a.day2 group by id) where id;
```

However it gives an error: 
You can't specify target table 'vacation_days' for update in FROM clause

Please let me know what I am missing.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
update vacation_days 
    set free = days_CurrYear * (select a.rate
                                from Algorithm a  
                                where vacation_days.work_days between a.day1 and a.day2
                               );
```